# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.ActionBarWindow

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am Using the ToolBar in my  app . When i am trying to use tool bar app is crashing.

**"java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.ActionBarWindow
"**.

I went through stackoverflow answers but  none of them solves my problem.

Here is my Code :

**app_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@color/green_background_color">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Theme for Activity :**

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>
```

**Manifest Declaration:**

```
<activity
            android:name="in.chabu.activities.SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        </activity>
```

**Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.chabu.activities.SignUpActivity" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
```

I am using `Eclipse IDE`.

Comment: are you extending  **ActionBarActivity** ??

Answer (score 1):

Modify your style as below:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.....

**toolbar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" <!-- ID of toolbar -->
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

and you can do it without using any style with NOACTIONBAR.

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**style**

```
  <style name="DevenTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_accent_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_control_normal_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/my_control_activated_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/my_control_highlight_color</item>
</style>
```

**manifest**

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/DevenTheme" >
```

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:elevation="5dp" />
```

In style you can skip all the colors, since those for material design looks.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but ***building*** `appCompact-v7-lib` and `My project` solved the problem.